Confusion about the sign of separation constant to use when solving PDE-IBVPs
This is just a general question regarding solving PDE-IBVPs for the standard Heat, Wave, Laplace equations with the Method of characteristics (in 1D and 2D respectively). Could someone please explain when I should use λ or -λ as the separation constant for wave, heat, laplace equations boundary value problems?
from what I observe, heat and wave tend to take -λ due to having a temporal variable, but what about Laplace?
I've seen both λ and -λ be posited. Take for e.g. this Wave equation problem:
Q1: Solve the Laplace equation:
[25 pts] Solve the Laplace equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0
$$
in the rectangle $0 \leq x \leq 3,0 \leq y \leq 2$, with the following boundary conditions:

$u(0, y)=0$ for $0 \leq y \leq 2$,
$u(3, y)=0$ for $0 \leq y \leq 2$,
$u(x, 0)=0$ for $0 \leq x \leq 3$,
$u(x, 2)=20 \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi x}{3}\right)$ for $0 \leq x \leq 3$.

Solution: We are solving the Laplace equation
$$
\frac{\partial_u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0
$$
Assurning the solution is of the form $u(x, y)=X(x) Y(y)$, and substituting into the PDE gives:
$$
\frac{X^n(x)}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y^{\prime \prime}(y)}{Y(y)}=\lambda
$$
which leads to two ordinary differential equations:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
X^{\prime \prime}(z)+\lambda X(x)=0 \\
Y^{\prime \prime \prime}(y)-\lambda Y(y)=0
\end{array}
$$
etc.
In this question, they used $\lambda$ as the separation constant, but in this Wave equation, they use $-\lambda$:
Q2: Find the solation to the following PDEIBVP:
$\begin{aligned} u_{t t} & =9 u_{x x}, & & x \in[0,2] \quad t \in \mathbb{R}, \\ u(0, t) & =0=u_x(2, t), & & x \in[0,2], \\ u(x, 0) & =3 \sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)+2 \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi x}{4}\right), & & t \in \mathbb{R}, \\ u_t(x, 0) & =0 . & & t \in \mathbb{R} .\end{aligned}$
You can either separate variables, or if you remember the formala, you can quote that.
Solution:
Solution: Using separation of variables, we make the ansatz:
$$
u(x, t)=X(x) T(t)
$$
Substituting this into the PDE gives the separation of variables:
$$
\frac{T^{\prime \prime}(t)}{T(t)}=9 \frac{X^{\prime \prime}(x)}{X(x)}=-\lambda,
$$
leading to two ODEs,
$$
\begin{aligned}
X^{\prime \prime}(x)+\frac{\lambda}{9} X(x) & =0 \\
T^{\prime \prime}(t)+\lambda T(t) & =0
\end{aligned}
$$

It does not matter if you use $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$, it is an arbitrary constant in both cases. The proper sign for $\lambda$ (or $-\lambda$) comes from solving the ode's and noting if we are generating more solutions than just the zero solution.

Right, but I believe that I have been told something along the lines that positing $-\lambda$ rather than $\lambda$ simplifies the working a great deal for PDEs with a temporal variable. Is this true? And is it also true for Laplace? Or should I just always use $\lambda$ and reason out the cases?
